# RadDataForm fails with an array index insert error when I add a custom PropertyValidator to my son metadata validators array

Tags: angular, nativescript

- I am using NativeScript 6 with 
  Angular.
- The metadata for the form object is defined in the TypeScript component as an object, which is referenced by the RadDataForm element in the component's template file.
- If I specify only RadDataForm built-in validators, everything works as expected.
- There is documentation covering much of this area, but I have not found an example which shows the son metadata for using it; I assume I am doing something wrong here.
- The xml examples appear to simply reference the class name of the Custom Validator and specify any parameters.  The documentation implied that the son would work the same way.
- With the TestValidator (custom validator) in the metadata, I get this error:
  CONSOLE ERROR [native code]: ERROR Error: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
  If I remove it from the metadata, everything works as expected.
- I have found a couple of less elegant work-arounds; using the (propertyValidate)="dfPropertyValidate($event)" validate handler on RadDataForm, and the (tap)="onTap()" tag.  These are documented, seem to work as I expect, but do require validation logic be split from the other form metadata.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, I am blind so cannot be sure if my formatting of this post is coming out as I expect.  Please let me know if it is difficult to read...  Thanks.

Thanks in advance for any clues!

### Template code:

```
<StackLayout #container>
    <RadDataForm #loginForm [source]="user"
        [metadata]="userMetadata"
        ></RadDataForm>
    <Button [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign in' : 'Sign Up'" class="submit-button" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

### Component Code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PropertyValidator } from "nativescript-ui-dataform";
import { UserService } from '../../shared/user/user.service';
import { Page } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/page';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "gr-main",
    providers: [UserService],
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['login-common.css', 'login.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    private _user: any;
    public userMetadata: any;
    public isLoggingIn = true;
    @ViewChild('loginForm', {static: false}) loginForm: ElementRef;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
        private page: Page
    ) {}

    get user(): any { return this._user; }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this._user = { email: '', password: '' };

        this.userMetadata = {
            "isReadOnly": false,
            "commitMode": "Immediate",
            "validationMode": "Immediate",
            "propertyAnnotations": [
                {
                    "required": true,
                    "name": "email",
                    "displayName": "E-Mail",
                    "index": 0,
                    "editor": "text",
                    "validators": [
                        { "name": "NonEmpty" }, 
                        { "name": "TestValidator" },
                        { "name": "MaximumLength", "params": { "length": 10 } }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": true,
                    "name": "password",
                    "displayName": "password",
                    "index": 1,
                    "editor": "Password",
                    "validators": [{ "name": "NonEmpty" }]
                },
            ]
        }
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
        this.page.backgroundImage = 'res://bg_login';
        console.log("user =" + this.user.email);
    }

    public submit() {
        let loginForm = this.loginForm.nativeElement;
        loginForm.validateAll()
            .then(result => {
                if( result ) { this.login() }
            });
    }

    private login() {
        this.userService.login(this.user)
                .subscribe(
                    () => {
                        this.userService.getRefData()
                            .subscribe(
                            () => this.router.navigate(['/pickEvent']),
                            (error) => alert('Unfortunately we could not load reference data for your account.')
                        );
                    },
                    (error) => alert('Unfortunately we could not access your account.')
                );
    }

}

export class TestValidator extends PropertyValidator {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.errorMessage = "Please enter: test";
    }

    public validate(value: any, propertyName: string): boolean {
        return value.toLowerCase() === "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the documentation is not very clear about this piece, you will have to register the validator and add it to your HTML template Or add it to the entity once it's created. Otherwise there is no way for the compiler to get reference of your custom class.

Comment: Can this be done in my component code?  Can you show the change I need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an easy way to do this, had to play with native objects a bit. You have to wait for editor update event, check the property name if matches then add the custom validator.

```
    onEditorUpdate(event) {
        if (event.propertyName === "email") {
            if (isAndroid) {
                const validator = event.entityProperty.getValidator();
                if (validator instanceof com.telerik.widget.dataform.engine.PropertyValidatorSet) {
                    validator.add(new TestValidator().android);
                }
            } else {
                const validator = event.entityProperty.validators;
                if (validator instanceof NSMutableArray) {
                    validator.addObject(new TestValidator().ios);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ChuQh9)

Comment: This solution still splits my validation metadata into 2 places, but I much prefer this solution as it keeps all validation workflow under the control of RadDataForm'.

Comment: Yes, it is just a workaround. You may still raise a feature request on [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues) for supporting custom validator in meta data itself.